# Switching Databases inside of for loop MySQL Node.js , its not switching fast enough/they are overlapping?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

just having a problem when switching between DB's (all hosted on same connection) in Node.js.

Here my code here:

Db.js setup (probably not important to look at but thought it should be included):

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
let assure_api;
const dbSettings = require('./settings.json').db_settings

function connectMainDB() {
    if (!assure_api) {
        assure_api = mysql.createConnection({
            host: dbSettings.assure_api_settings.host,
            user: dbSettings.user,
            password: dbSettings.password,
            database:  dbSettings.assure_api_settings.name,
            port: dbSettings.assure_api_settings.port
        });

        assure_api.connect(function(err){
            if(!err) {
                console.log('Main DB is connected!');
            } else {
                console.log('Error connecting database!');

            }
        });
    }
    return assure_api;
}

function connectDbs() {

    let dbHosts;
    let dbConnections = {}
    assure_api.query("SELECT DISTINCT wh_db_host FROM license", (err, result) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
    else {
        dbHosts = result;
        for(i=0; i < dbHosts.length; i++){
            let db = mysql.createConnection({
                host: dbHosts[i].wh_db_host,
                user: dbSettings.user,
                password: dbSettings.password
            })

            let dbName = dbHosts[i].wh_db_host
            console.log('Setup connection for ', dbName)


            dbConnections[dbHosts[i].wh_db_host] = db
        }
    }
})
   return dbConnections; 
}

function createTenantTable() {

    let tenantTable = {}
    assure_api.query("SELECT client_id, wh_db_host FROM license", (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        else { 
            for(i=0; i < result.length; i++){
                tenantTable[`${result[i].client_id}`] = result[i].wh_db_host
            }
        }
    })
    return tenantTable;
}





module.exports = {
    assure_api: connectMainDB(),
    dbConnections: connectDbs(),
    tenantTable: createTenantTable()
}
```

The route:

```
app.get('/getMatModes', function(req, res){

    assure_api.query("SELECT client_id FROM license", (err, result) => {
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        else {
            let schools = result;
            let temp = schools
            schools = [];


            for(let i=0; i < temp.length; i++){
                schools.push(temp[i].client_id)
            }


            let matModes = [];

            async.forEachOf(schools, function(dataElement, i, inner_callback){
                let query = `SELECT parameter_value FROM parameter_data where parameter_name='maintenance_mode'`
                let schoolCode = dataElement;
                dbConnections[tenantTable[`${schoolCode}`]].query(`USE ${schoolCode}`, () => {

/*this is the line trying to debug which database is being looked at, because the values being 
returned in the query below were just simply wrong.*/
                    dbConnections[tenantTable[`${schoolCode}`]].query(`SELECT Database()`, (err, result) => {
                        console.log(result[0])
                    })
                        dbConnections[tenantTable[`${schoolCode}`]].query(query, (err, result) => {
                            if(err){
                                inner_callback(err)
                            }
                            else {
                                matModes.push(result, schoolCode)
                                inner_callback(null)
                            }



                        })
                    })

            },
            function(err){
                if(err){
                    throw err;
                }
                else{
                    console.log(matModes)
                }
            }
            )







        }
    })




})
```

You would expect the output to console to be:

```
RowDataPacket { 'Database()': 'new' }
RowDataPacket { 'Database()': 'joeys' }
RowDataPacket { 'Database()': 'rvw' }
RowDataPacket { 'Database()': 'sfx' }
RowDataPacket { 'Database()': 'tss' }
[
  [ RowDataPacket { parameter_value: '1' } ],
  'new',
  [ RowDataPacket { parameter_value: '1' } ],
  'joeys',
  [ RowDataPacket { parameter_value: '0' } ],
  'rvw',
  [ RowDataPacket { parameter_value: '0' } ],
  'sfx',
  [ RowDataPacket { parameter_value: '1' } ],
  'tss'
]
```

However the output is as such:

```
RowDataPacket { 'Database()': 'new' }
RowDataPacket { 'Database()': 'tss' }
RowDataPacket { 'Database()': 'tss' }
RowDataPacket { 'Database()': 'tss' }
RowDataPacket { 'Database()': 'tss' }
[
  [ RowDataPacket { parameter_value: '1' } ],
  'new',
  [ RowDataPacket { parameter_value: '1' } ],
  'joeys',
  [ RowDataPacket { parameter_value: '1' } ],
  'rvw',
  [ RowDataPacket { parameter_value: '1' } ],
  'sfx',
  [ RowDataPacket { parameter_value: '1' } ],
  'tss'
]
```

The above is just one of the many variations it randomly selects, all of the time is will always be able to make the first switch but the following switches are random if they succeed or not. How on earth do I fix this bug. I've literally spent days on it now and I'm going nuts. Someone please help.

**Edit:** As of 27/05/2020 I have a temporary work around but still looking for a fix as to why this is happening and how to solve it.

Comment: Instead of switching, why not maintain two connections and have a function that returns which one to use for a given task? You're manipulating a global variable here which is bad form.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, could you elaborate or show some code. Also,its not just two connections, its upwards of like 50 or 100 depending on how large scale this app gets.

Comment: All the more reason to not swap. Keep a connection pool open *per endpoint* and have a function to check out and return connections.

Comment: Also watch out for doing things like `\`${schoolCode}\`` where that should be `schoolCode`. No need for a template string with one thing in it.

Comment: hey guys i changed the setup so it just creates a new connection for every database, and now its working fine. I have all of those database connections stored in an object that i can reference with ```schoolCode``` . It works now, just wondering if this is the right way of doing things

Comment: Only way to find out for sure is to test it under load, not just light poking in your dev environment. Remember MySQL has a 100 connection limit by default so you may exhaust that pretty quick.

Comment: Who came up with this storage scheme any way?